# How to re-order, hide, unhide extension icons on Chrome toolbar programmatically

Tags: c#, windows, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a Google Chrome extension that is installed and works in tandem with a native application on windows.

Using Chrome Extension management API, I can easily enable and disable other Chrome extensions.

Manually, a user can right click on a Chrome Extension icon on Chrome's toolbar and select 'Hide' to hide an extension icon or use the mouse to drag icons around to re-order them.

I am wondering if there is a way to do this programmatically either from a chrome extension or from a native windows application (C#).

Comment: There's no API for this. You'll have to emulate the mouse click-and-drag over the icons in your native app. It might be complicated, especially to calculating the correct screen coordinate, but should be doable.

Comment: I actually thought about this, but knowing exactly where an Icon is on the screen is a little tricky considering that the toolbar and it's icons do not have window handle (I checked with spy++).